# Why is this Solaris 8 SPARC install panicking on my Sun Blade 100?

Tags: solaris

I have a Sun Blade 100 with 2GB of NOS RAM, an NOS NVRAM module, and a recently shrink-wrapped set of Solaris 8 Installation CDROMs.  When it comes up, the memory check passes OK and the system proceeds to wait for link on the NIC.

When I STOP+A it and run probe-ide, I see the CDROM and hard disk.  Then I boot cdrom and the system seems to load from the disc for a while and then panic.

What's going wrong?  How can I troubleshoot this and proceed?

[probe-ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egFal.png)

[boot cdrom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMdtP.jpg)

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as too broad.  Flagged for reopening.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19127-01/blade100.ws/816-1796-13/816-1796-13.pdf, page 1 for the likely reason this isn't working.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The problem was that I was trying to install Solaris 8 10/00.  The document that you offered answers the question nicely.  Thanks again!